# menu link which show a div in another div

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I created a menu with links (#) which aims to show & hide a div thanks to the onclick attribute.
For example the link "home" can hide/show the div "contentHome", the link "contact" can hide/show the div "contentContact".

The problem I have is that the container div "content" includes the div "contentHome" and "contentContact" when i click on the 2 links one time...

Here is a part of my code :

```
   <li><a href="#" onclick="toggle('contentHome');" ><?php echo $lang['MENU_ACCUEIL'];?>
<div id="content">
<div id="contentHome">  
    <img src="Images/photo.jpg" class="imgphoto" alt="Simplepic"  />
    <?php echo $lang['TEXTE_ACCUEIL'];?>
    <img src="Images/work.png" class="imgwork" height="100" width="100" alt="Travaux" /> 
   <?php echo $lang['TEXTE_SOON'];?>
</div>
<div id="contentContact">
    ...
   </div>
   </div>
```

The position is static, I can't put a z-index and when I put display:none;, divs don't want to load.

What do you think ? I just wanted to create a dynamic menu with div but the php includes makes me struggle...

Comment: Your question is confusing.
Do you have 2 links?
One to home and another to contact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i've created some example of toggle with divs.

```
 <li><a href="#" id="lnk_contentHome">Toggle Red</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" id="lnk_contentContact">Toggle Blue</a></li>


<div id="content">
<div class="toggled-item" id="contentHome">  
    <div style="width:200px; background-color:#f00; height:200px;"></div>

</div>
<div class="toggled-item" id="contentContact">  
                <div style="width:200px; background-color:#00f; height:200px;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#lnk_contentHome, #lnk_contentContact").click(function(){
        $(".toggled-item").hide();
        var target = $(this).attr("id").split("_")[1];
        $("#" + target).toggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ow7dd12f/5/

Hope helps.

Comment: Yeeaaaah that was exactly what i needed, thank you very much, you made my day ! But a last problem occurs with this, the toggle red and blue are together if i click on the 2 links and i don't want it. How can i correct that?

Comment: Yes, the idea is when i click on the link, the js code delete the previous div and open the new. For example if i click on the "Toggle Red" and then click on the "Toggle Blue", the toggle red disappear and the toggle blue take the place of the Toggle red

Comment: I just updated the code above and the jsfiddle example. (I created a class named "toggled-item" in content divs and hide it before toggle clicked link)
Can you test it again?

Regards

Comment: That's exactly the effect i was looking for. I adapt your code with the mine and i'm glad it's finally working. Thank you a lot for your help